# XOR of all integers

Tags: javascript, xor

I’m a jr web dev trying to improve my logic/algorithm skills, while studying I have found coding challenges like the one below, for this kind of problems can you point me in the right direction, I mean what should I study, check, review? And for the below challenge can you give me an idea on how to solve it, maybe some pseudo code?

> CHALLENGE:
>
> You are given Q queries. Each of the query contains two integers L and R.
>   For each query print out the XOR of all integers in the given range which have only one bit in their binary representation.
>
> Input format:
>
> - The first line contains Q queries.
> - Next Q lines contain two integers L and R
>
> Output format:
>
> Print one integer for each query denoting the answer
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 ≤ Q ≤ 105
>   1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 1018
>
> Sample input
>
> 1
>   60       -  130
>
> Sample Output
>
> 192

What I have tried so far:

```
const sumQuery = (q, n) => {
  let bitCount = [];
  //travers the bits
  for(let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     // check whether the current bit is
     let temp = Math.sqrt(arr[j]) * 2 );
     if(temp % 2 !== 0 ) {
      console.log(temp)
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Only powers of 2 have one bit in their binary representation. So, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 are the only numbers you need to care about. For the example test case, it is 64 ^ 128 = 192

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to your question, I will try to answer them both separately.

1) What should you study to improve your logic / algorithmic skills?
First, you should determine your purpose for doing that (trying to get a better job / building fundamentals in cs / learning how specific systems or frameworks function and etc). Once you figure out what your exact reason for trying to improve, it will be much easier to determine what kind of knowledge / skills you will need to gather. Here are some recommendations for the paths that I mentioned:

a) Trying to get a better job. If that is the case - my only recommendation is practise your coding interview questions. Depth of your knowledge doesn’t often matter as much as your ability to solve these during an interview (based on my personal experience). Here are a few places where you can start:

- https://leetcode.com
- https://www.codewars.com/
- cracking the coding interview (book)

b) Building fundamentals in CS. There are a few ways to do this (including going to school). If you are looking for a program, my recommendations are as follows:

- Free full computer science program outline (https://github.com/ossu/computer-science)
- Famous free MIT courses (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/)
- Paid Data Structure and Algorithms track in Coursera (https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-structures-algorithms)

c) Better understanding of certain systems. For that - I would highly recommend reading through the system implementation or doing a deeper tutorial on it. Recommendations:

- Great js library to read through and understand - Immutable-js (https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js)
- Rails Tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning)

2) How to solve your specific coding challenge. Here is a great breakdown of 80% of the challenge that you are presenting described by someone else (https://www.codechef.com/PRJRF14/problems/XORSN).
I would recommend getting a solid understanding of binary data and the concept of XOR between integers.

Possible solution steps (I will not write it out for you in js, since you want to solve it yourself):

- Like mentioned by Maaz Syed Adeeb - you only need to account for powers of 2 when searching for the XOR between the given integers range (since they are the only ones that have one bit binary representations).
- Make note of all powers of 2 in the given constraint `valid = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]`
- Determine which of these lie within given range
- Convert each `valid` integer to binary
- Find XOR between each `valid` integer using this logic

```
Rule 1 : If both bits are 1 then XOR’ed bit will be 0.
Rule 2 : If both bits are 0 then XOR’ed bit will be 0.
Rule 3 : If one bit is 0 and one bit is 1 XOR’ed bit will be 1.
```

- Convert binary code from your last XOR comparison into an integer

Good luck!

Comment: You can just suggest using the XOR operator in js, that is ^. So the last 3 steps could be avoided and just the numbers in the range could be XOR'ed.

Comment: Thank you, Maaz!

I just thought that doing those steps for OP themselves, would be a great practise of writing this kind of logic. However - you are right, I should have shared that `^` operator exists for that purpose.

I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Maaz, Artem, thank you both guys! Im now taking a look at Bitwise AND,OR and XOR, at the beginning I didnt had an idea on how to solve the challenge. I also see the use of `^` in a section in leetcode...the challenge doesnt look that dificult now :)

Comment: Glad, we could help :)